# System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException when trying to GET a json object web api

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to send an object type UserEntry to the client.
the route I used was: http://localhost:3027/api/userapi/getinfo?username=myUsername 
What is the cause of this error or what is wrong with my code?

```
    [HttpGet, Route("api/userapi/getinfo")]
    public async Task<string> getUserInfo([FromUri]string username)
    {
        UserEntry u = await UserEntry.getUserInfo(username);
        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(u);
    }
```

Here is what inner exception shows:

InnerException: {
Message: "An error has occurred.",
ExceptionMessage: "Invalid operation. The connection is closed.",
ExceptionType: "System.InvalidOperationException",
StackTrace: " at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.GetOpenConnection() at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.get_ServerVersion()"
}

I checked and made sure that there was no error in connecting with the database, but it still shows error.

I temporarily solved it by making it synchronous

I solved it by making it synchronous

```
        [HttpGet,Route("api/userapi/getinfo")]
        public SimpleUser getUserInfo([FromUri]string username)
        {
            var ur = new UserRepository();
            return ur.getUser(username).First(); 
        }


    public IEnumerable<SimpleUser> getUser(string username)
    {
        UserEntryDBContext context = new UserEntryDBContext();
        UserEntry u = context.Users.Where( x => x.username == username).FirstOrDefault();
        List<SimpleUser> s = new List<SimpleUser>();
           s.Add(new SimpleUser(u));

        return s;
    }
```

but I still have no idea what causes the error nor how can I make it asynchronous.

Comment: your controller is getting invoked?

Comment: yes, I debug it and the action in the controller is invoked. I just added the inner exception, maybe that clarifies more?

Comment: it is obvious your call to retrieve `UserEntry` is throwing the error.Debug your data access code.Let me see the method.

Comment: I solved it by making it sunchronous [HttpGet,      Route("api/userapi/getinfo")]
        public SimpleUser getUserInfo([FromUri]string username)
        {
            var ur = new UserRepository();
            return ur.getUser(username).First(); 
        }